# wxPython to exe with PyInstaller?

Tags: python, wxpython, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to get a wxPython app working as an exe. I've heard that PyInstaller is now superior to py2exe. I'd like to include my .ico and two .png files that the script requires to run. What would the spec file for this look like? I can't seem to find a decent example anywhere. I have PyInstaller installed, but I can't find this "makespec" anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my PyInstaller projects, I'd normally just have a runtime check to [see if the app's frozen](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#adapting-to-being-frozen) and adjust the paths to the bitmaps accordingly.  So something like this to handle PyInstaller and regular Python application:

```
def app_path():
    """Returns the base application path."""
    if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
        # Handles PyInstaller
        return os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    return os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Comment: But what would the spec look like?

Comment: @tkbx it doesn't come in to play if you do it this way - you're just telling Python where to find the bitmap on its own.  So you'd just add e.g. your icons folder to the PyInstaller dist folder after the build.

Comment: And the .exe looks in it's (dist) dir for these files? Would the folder have to be installed somewhere on the system?

Comment: Right, the icons folder would be put under the dist folder and gets installed on the system.

Answer (score 1):

Checking for `sys.frozen` is a really good approach.  You can also look into `img2py` which will let you load the binary data for images into a .py file.  Later, instead of having to open files, they can be imported.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = Analysis(['script.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\source-control\\GITHUB\\projectname'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,)

a.datas += [( 'images', r'C:\Users\igorl\Pictures\hzgJUXi5l4o.jpg', 'DATA')]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name=os.path.join('dist', 'script.exe'),
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
```